# Blazor on .NET Core 3.0.0 Preview 5 - No Scaffolders error

Tags: c#, razor-pages, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm dipping my toes into Blazor, and I'm running into some trouble.

I have a Visual Studio 2019 Professional (v16.1.6) version installed, and .NET Core 3.0.0 Preview 5:

```
C:\projects> dotnet info

Welcome to .NET Core 3.0!
SDK Version: 3.0.100-preview5-011568
```

I created a "Blazor ASP.NET Core hosted" project from VS 2019, and I can run it just fine.

Now I wanted to add a "Blazor" page to the `Pages` folder:

[image]

but I get this error:

[image]

Do I need to install anything more than basic VS2019Pro and .NET Core 3.0.0 preview 5? If so: what am I missing, what do I need in addition?

OK, so I tried to circumvent this trouble by adding a "regular" `*.cshtml` page and then just renaming it to `mypage.razor`. Trouble with that is: the `@page "/mypage"` directive at the top of the file isn't recognized ("The name 'page' isn't recognized in the current context") - why? Can I fix that somehow??

Any inputs are most welcome! Thanks a heap

Comment: @HenkHolterman: thanks - that helped a lot - off to do some more Blazor exploring!

Comment: Do note, MS states "We've integrated the Blazor component model into ASP.NET Core 3.0 and renamed it to Razor Components.": https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2019/01/29/aspnet-core-3-preview-2/

Comment: @LGSon In the very next preview, they renamed it to Server-side Blazor: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-4/

Comment: @MikeBrind -- Thanks Mike...lets hope they stay with Blazor, to avoid any further confusions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Why don't you migrate to preview 6 ?
- You can't add a Razor Page to a Blazor app. Razor Page is a thing you add to your Razor Pages application. In Blazor no such objects as Razor Pages exist. You should add a Component. You may have a Component page, as for instance, MyDocPage, which contains child components.
- In order to use IUriHelper, you have to inject it into your components. It is automatically added into the DI container by the Blazor framework.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I've been reluctant to go to preview-6 because of all the problems with EF Core in preview 6 .....

Comment: So in a Blazor project, you have what looks and feels like "pages", with a `.razor` extensions - but those are **NOT** Razor pages...... thanks Microsoft for the total confusion!! :-( Also: adding a regular C# class doesn't work without a fair amount of manual tweaking as I just learned.... you need to change the build action from "C# compiler" to "Content", and you need to set the "Custom Tool" for the file to "MSBuild:RazorGenerateComponentDeclarationDesignTime" - then it works ..... PHEW!!

Comment: @marc_s, so don't go... But do you understand why you've got the error ? It is explained above...No Razor Pages in Blazor.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: well - that was the key - renaming **before** adding! That works for me, too - thanks for the tip

Comment: @marc_s, Razor Pages are very different from Blazor Compoents in functionality terms. They look very similar because both uses Razor syntax. Previously Blazor components had .cshtml extension  just like Razor pages, which was very confusing, but now Blazor Compoents have .razor extension. This change was mainly done so that the compiler can distinguish between Razor Pages and Blazor Components. Also, instead of the functions block it is recommended to use the code block  in Blazor, and the functions block in Razor Pages...

Comment: @Issac: yes, I realize that now, looking deeper into it - it's just rather confusing when you have something that looks and feels like a page and it has a `.razor` extension - but **no, no** - it's **NOT** a Razor page! And it's listed as the top item when doing an `Add....` too ..... Kinda goes against the *Principle of Least Surprise* and threw me off a bit

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, dev issue.

You can see that it has happend before, they have fixed it and now again:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/431328/scaffolding-error-there-are-no-scaffolders-support.html

Report a bug and it will be fixed again :P